# How can I clean up and remove unnecessary steps from recorded macro?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I'm new to VBA and I'm looking to tidy up the below macro that was recorded and remove any details that are insterted by default and don't really need to be there  or remove any details that aren't necessary and just clutter up the code.  Can anyone give some advice?

```
     With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Normal")
    .IncludeNumber = True
    .IncludeFont = True
    .IncludeAlignment = True
    .IncludeBorder = True
    .IncludePatterns = True
    .IncludeProtection = True
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Normal").NumberFormat = "#,##0.0;[Red](#,##0.0);-"
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 1")
    .IncludeNumber = False
    .IncludeFont = True
    .IncludeAlignment = False
    .IncludeBorder = True
    .IncludePatterns = True
    .IncludeProtection = False
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 1").Borders(xlLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 1").Borders(xlRight).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 1").Borders(xlTop).LineStyle = xlNone
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 1").Borders(xlBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ThemeColor = 4
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 1").Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 1").Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 1").Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = 0
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 1")
    .IncludeNumber = False
    .IncludeFont = True
    .IncludeAlignment = False
    .IncludeBorder = True
    .IncludePatterns = False
    .IncludeProtection = False
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 2")
    .IncludeNumber = False
    .IncludeFont = True
    .IncludeAlignment = False
    .IncludeBorder = True
    .IncludePatterns = False
    .IncludeProtection = False
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 2").Borders(xlLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 2").Borders(xlRight).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 2").Borders(xlTop).LineStyle = xlNone
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 2").Borders(xlBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ThemeColor = 4
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 2").Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 2").Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 4")
    .IncludeNumber = False
    .IncludeFont = True
    .IncludeAlignment = False
    .IncludeBorder = False
    .IncludePatterns = False
    .IncludeProtection = False
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 4").Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 11
    .Bold = True
    .Italic = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .Strikethrough = False
    .ThemeColor = 2
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With
  With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Total")
    .IncludeNumber = False
    .IncludeFont = True
    .IncludeAlignment = False
    .IncludeBorder = True
    .IncludePatterns = False
    .IncludeProtection = False
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Total").Borders(xlLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Total").Borders(xlRight).LineStyle = xlNone
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Total").Borders(xlTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ThemeColor = 2
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Total").Borders(xlBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ThemeColor = 2
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Total").Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Total").Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=21
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Percent").NumberFormat = "0.00%;[Red](0.00%);-"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular sample, all lines related to `ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 1")` could be grouped and enclosed the whole code in a `With..End With` construct. Idem for Normal style:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Normal")
    .IncludeNumber = True
    .IncludeFont = True
    .IncludeAlignment = True
    .IncludeBorder = True
    .IncludePatterns = True
    .IncludeProtection = True
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.0;[Red](#,##0.0);-"
End With   
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Heading 1")
    .IncludeNumber = False
    .IncludeFont = True
    .IncludeAlignment = False
    .IncludeBorder = True
    .IncludePatterns = True
    .IncludeProtection = False
    .Borders(xlLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ThemeColor = 4
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
```

Generally you will also want to remove all `Activate`. Intead of

```
Range("g2").Activate
ActiveCell.Value = 6
```

you would write: `Range("g2").Value = 6`